# Spring data : issue with OneToOne relationship

Tags: jpa, spring-data

I am developping a webapp (Spring J2EE/angularjs)

I want to set a relationship between two entities :
citizen (id, lastName, city)
city (id, cityName)

A citizen live in only one city.

I need to find a city from a citizen.
I don't need to find a citizen from a city.

I have done that :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "citizen")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Citizen implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne
    private City city;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class City implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "city_name")
    private String cityName;
}
```

In database I have inserted data. Citizen 1, 2 and 3 are linked to City 1
 and Citizen 4 is linked to City 2

When I try to load all citizen, I am getting the error:
More than one row with the given identifier was found: 1, for class: com.myApp.rh.domain.Citizen

What's wrong in my entities?

Thanks

Comment: Since one `City` can have many `Citizen`, please change it to `ManyToOne`  instead of `OneToOne` on the `private City city;` and try. Also can you show your logic to load all the citizens you are using?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing the @JoinColumn annotation in your Citizen entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "citizen")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Citizen implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", unique = true)
    private City city;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class City implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "city_name")
    private String cityName;
}
```